# Word meaning "impractical, didactic, theoretical"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am in search of a word which I'm not sure exists. What is a good way to describe something which:

— has little to no consequence

— is possibly important in theory

— would be considered good form to do correctly

Here's an example. Suppose you are writing an essay for a professor who really cares about formatting. You italicize a section of words and also italicize the period which follows, even though the period should not have been italicized. Obviously nobody can tell whether a period is italicized or not, but if your professor opened your essay in a word processor, they might note that you had italicized incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example suggests 'pedantry' (n.), which is practiced by 'pedants' (n.pl.), who are called 'pedantic' (adj.):

> **ped·ant·ry**
>   1. The ostentatious display of academic knowledge, or **undue attention paid to minor details or formal rules**: *His detailed research was dismissed as pedantry.*
>   2. An instance of pedantic behavior: grew tired of his pedantries.

[pedantry. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved February 21 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pedantry . Bold emphasis mine.]

Funny you should ask on this site, where practicing pedants produce prolix pedantries.

Comment: Excellent answer. In the interest of pedantry, I've corrected some typos :)

Comment: @Charon, I appreciate the thought but, not being British, I overpedanted your pedantry with the correct, that is, US American English spelling.

Comment: Fair play. I was unaware that our respective vernaculars differed in that regard.

Comment: @Charon, and I, for my part, was unaware the British used the spelling with 's' for the verb but not the noun...I would've been sure it was 's' for both had I not looked it up pedantically.

Comment: So you'd rather use, Elliot, for your Pr., instead of "pedantry", the simple word "formal", I guess...

Answer (score 2):

You could say ***it's academic,*** which means that what you have done serves no practical benefit but has been done purely in the interest of being strictly accurate or correct.

> **Academic**
>
> - Having no important consequence or relevancy: *The debate about who is to blame has become academic because the business has left town.*
> - Hypothetical or theoretical and not expected to produce an immediate or practical result; *an academic discussion*; *an academic question*

<sub>TFD</sub>

Comment: Charon : Nice try ! But in University, "academic" is a normal word & from there we don't understand when we are told it's "academic !" ; there we say : So ?

Comment: Welcome Charon, on the other hand the question is rather unclear....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **nicety**. A nicety is:

- generally of little importance
- but indicative of proper form or behavior
- could become important under unlikely circumstances

The last point is debatable, but modern usage often seems to equate "nicety" with something that is mostly, but indeed not always dispensable.

Edit: I cannot quite agree with the accepted answer, **pedantry**. First, it is quite negative, often suggesting excessive concern, narrow-mindedness or ostentatiousness (see, e.g., Merriam Webster). Second, I rarely hear an issue or concern (e.g., formatting) itself described as pedantic or pedantry. Pedantry describes a behavior or one who behaves (the pedant), but it is not so much a property of the issue about which one is being pedantic - which I assume OP was looking for ("a good way to describe something which").

Answer (score -2):

Your question is complex, not difficult but recovers several points.
— has little to no consequence : void/vain
— is possibly important in theory : so it's no little to no consequence...But the worst comes whith the last *requisit* : — would be considered good form to do correctly ; so this leads to think that without the good form you can't do correctly...

And what follows for example is no help at all to understand your whole nebulous request concerning a "period". Are you talking about *dot* or *duration* ? (I beleive it's not *menses*)
However, I'd say you ask us to "give you a pull".

You could use : **flourish ; formal ; ornamental**

*Pedantic* is insulting. Don't forget who you're talking to : you depend on him.
(However, in university we don't blame you if you didn't underline ponctuation.)